# Load csv data with partition in spark 2.0

Tags: java, apache-spark

In Spark 2.0, i have the following method which loads the data into dataset

```
public Dataset<AccountingData> GetDataFrameFromTextFile()
{     // The schema is encoded in a string
    String schemaString = "id firstname lastname accountNo";

    // Generate the schema based on the string of schema
    List<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String fieldName : schemaString.split("\t")) {
        StructField field = DataTypes.createStructField(fieldName, DataTypes.StringType, true);
        fields.add(field);
    }
    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);

    return  sparksession.read().schema(schema)
            .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
            .option("sep", "|")
            .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", true)
            .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace ", true)
            .csv("D:\\HadoopDirectory\Employee.txt").as(Encoders.bean(Employee.class));
}
```

and in my driver code, Map operation is called on the dataset

```
    Dataset<Employee> rowDataset = ad.GetDataFrameFromTextFile();

    Dataset<String> map = rowDataset.map(new MapFunction<Employee, String>() {
        @Override
        public String call(Employee emp) throws Exception {
            return  TraverseRuleByADRow(emp);
        }
    },Encoders.STRING());
```

When i run the driver program in spark local mode with 8 cores on my laptop, i see 8 partitions split the input file.May i know whether there is a way to load the file in more than 8 partitions, say 100 or 1000 partitions?

I know this is achievable if the source data is from sql server table via jdbc.

```
sparksession.read().format("jdbc").option("url", urlCandi).option("dbtable", tableName).option("partitionColumn", partitionColumn).option("lowerBound", String.valueOf(lowerBound))
                .option("upperBound", String.valueOf(upperBound))
                .option("numPartitions", String.valueOf(numberOfPartitions))
                .load().as(Encoders.bean(Employee.class));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use repartition() method from Dataset. According to [Scaladoc](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L350), there is no option to set number of paritions while reading

Comment: in my code i used coalesce(1,true) which outputs to a single file. I still see the number of partitions to the number of cores available on the machine. If i used coalesce(1000,true), i see 1000 small files in my output directory but it doesn't help to split the file into 1000 partitions. `sourceDataSet.toJavaRDD().coalesce(1,true).saveAsTextFile(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY);`